# Importing a CSV File in MongoDB

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I am importing a large 9.5 million record file in MongoDB using MongoImport. The CSV file was created for SQL Server Import operations and because the data in SQL table contained quotes(") itself. So, it was generating error importing in SQL.That is why, it has pipe (|) as the text qualifier and as the column delimiter.

While using MongoImport I can't find anything related to setting column delimiter and text qualifier by myself.

The screenshot contains the error message
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Since it is using `|` as delimiter it's not longer valid CSV.

Your options are to export data to JSON, TSV or CSV and then use `mongoimport` or do it programmatically which will be pretty valid and fast option since mongo doesn't wait till it's inserted so it will be pretty fast.